# how to iterate over a list and assign items to a variables using python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

How to iterate over a list and assign each item to a variable until now i am able to iterate over the list and print all the items but i want to store each item in a variable in order to use it later like so.

Here i am hardcoding the variables... what i want is to assign values during the iteration.

## code:

```
tl = pd.unique(df[item1].tolist())

var1 = df[item1][df[item1]==tl[0]]
var2 = df[item1][df[item1]==tl[1]]
var3 = df[item1][df[item1]==tl[2]]
var4 =df[item1][df[item1]==tl[3]]


print("number of var1  is: {}".format(len(var1)))
print("number of var2  is: {}".format(len(var2)))
print("number of var3  is: {}".format(len(var3)))
print("number of var4 is: {}".format(len(var4)))
```

## what i want :

```
tl = pd.unique(df[item1].tolist())
                for column in tl:
                    print(column)
```

Comment: Please provide a sample input and the desired output, it's very hard to tell what you want.

Comment: i did ...i want to assign each item of the list to a variable as i showed in the first chunk of code

Comment: What will the names of the variables be?

Comment: the name will be `the value of the item` where the iterated list will contain  distinct values

Comment: @Georges **don't do this** Don't dynamically create variables. Use a *container*. Like a `list` in this case

Comment: In this case, just `var = [df[item1][df[item1] == t] for t in tl]`

Comment: your comment is the perfect answer  but how to use the created variable from the list comprehension in this :
`slice_pie=[format(100*len(var0)/df.shape[0]), format(100*len(var1)/df.shape[0]),format(100*len(var2)/df.shape[0]), format(100*len(var3)/df.shape[0])]`

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, row in df.T.iterrows():
    for c, x in enumerate(row.unique()):
        print(f'number of row{c+1} is: {x}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `n` is the length of the list (you can have that easily)
You can replace all this:

```
var1 = df[item1][df[item1]==tl[0]]
var2 = df[item1][df[item1]==tl[1]]
var3 = df[item1][df[item1]==tl[2]]
var4 = df[item1][df[item1]==tl[3]]
...
varn = df[item1][df[item1]==tl[n]]
```

With a list comprehension:

```py
var = [df[item1][df[item1]==t] for t in tl]
```

Now to print:

```
for i in range(n):
    print(f"number of var{i}  is: {len(var[i])}")
```

Comment: the range  is not fix its the `len` of the list

Comment: Answer updated with a variable `n` containing the length of the list

Comment: Don't use `n`, just `[df[item1][df[item1] == t] for t in tl]`